# Catch exceptions in async loading of dialog viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog, async-await

I have a `DialogViewModel` class with `async Task LoadData()` method. This method loads data asynchronously and shows this dialog, which notifies user about loading. Here is the code:

```
try
{
    var dialog = new DialogViewModel();
    var loadTask = dialog.LoadData();
    WindowManager.ShowDialog(dialog);
    await loadTask;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error("Error in DialogViewModel", ex);
    // Notify user about the error
}
```

When `LoadData` throws an exception, it isn't handled until user exits the dialog. It happens because exception is handled when calling `await`, and it's not happening until `WindowManager.ShowDialog(dialog)` completes.

What is the correct way to show a dialog with async loading? I've tried this ways:

1. Call `LoadData()` in `OnShow()`, constructor or similar. But this won't work if I'll need to show this dialog without any data
2. Call `await LoadData()` before showing the dialog. This way user have to wait for data to load before actually seeing the window, but I want the window to show up instantly with a loading indicator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239306/how-to-continue-executing-code-after-calling-showdialog

Comment: Unfortunately, the answers in this question aren't suitable for me. I have already wrote about `Show()`. I guess need to call 'LoadData()' from outside because only the caller determines whether to load data or not.
As for 'BackgroundWorker' - I hope that there is a way to do this with async-await...

Comment: Where does `WindowManager.ShowDialog()` come from? Is it Caliburn Micro?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter: it can be any `ShowDialog()` implementation, e.g. view injection.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there an explicit public `LoadData` method?

If this has to happen then do it inside the constructor asynchronously using `Task<T>` with a `ContinueWith` to process any exception generated by checking the `IsFaulted`property on the returned task.

This would address both issues you've highlighted.

A very simple example is shown below, obivously you're implementation will be more complicated.

```
public class DialogViewModel
{
    private Task _task;

    public DialogViewModel()
    {
        var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var data = GetDataCollection();
                return data;
            })
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    HasErrored = true;
                    ErrorMessage = "It's borked!";
                }
                else
                {
                    Data = t.Result;
                }
            }, context);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Data { get; private set; }

    public bool HasErrored { get; private set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetDataCollection()
    {
        return new List<string>()
        {
            "John",
            "Jack",
            "Steve"
        };
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to use `Task<T>` explicitly and want to use async\await functionality you could use a slightly different approach because you can't use async\await with a class constructor:

```
public class DialogViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Data { get; private set; }

    public bool HasErrored { get; private set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }

    async public static Task<DialogViewModel> BuildViewModelAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var data = await GetDataCollection();
            return new DialogViewModel(data);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new DialogViewModel("Failed!");
        }
    }

    private DialogViewModel(IEnumerable<string> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    private DialogViewModel(string errorMessage)
    {
        HasErrored = true;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    private async static Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDataCollection()
    {
        // do something async...
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new List<string>()
        {
            "John",
            "Jack",
            "Steve"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But then `LoadData()` will always be called, but I may want to show this dialog without loading any data (as I described in first case).

Comment: well, this is where i think you have an issue, either it should be called always or it should never be called. Because otherwise it is not obvious when it should be called...